# TypeCasting in Java for Interface

Tags: java, casting

Can someone please explain  the reason of below :

The below code gives compilation error because there is no relation between String and StringBuffer.

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
String ste = (String)str;
```

Similarly , below interfaces should give compilation error as Map and Collection interfaces are not related.

```
Map map = new HashMap();
Collection c = (Collection) map;
```

I tried finding on Google - All I got to know that Map is also considered in Collection Framework. But what i am  not getting is - how Compiler is not identifying it as an error for type match.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1

Answer (score 14):

The difference is that, since String and StringBuffer are two classes, there is absolutely no way for a class to extend both StringBuffer and String.

But since Collection and Map are interfaces, it's perfectly possible for a class to implement both Collection and Map. So the cast is valid: `map` could be an instance of a class that implements Map and also implements Collection.